# How to solve wooden octagon box puzzle?

Tags: mechanical-puzzles

This is a puzzle with a hidden mechanism I have had for probably 20 years and recently found. The two halves of the box can not rotate. There is something inside that rattles and rolls around, perhaps a bearing. I can pull the halves very slightly apart, enough to see a wooden circular interior in the middle of the octagon, and 2 dowels on either side of the cylinder that prevent the halves from rotating.

I have tried carefully pulling and pushing holding the puzzle at many different angles.

Anyone know the solution to this puzzle or have suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the ball feel or sound like it's bouncing against something inside?  There may be some sort of mechanism that's released when the ball gets to the right place.

Comment: The ball rolls and clunks. No luck trying to pull at different clunk sounds.

Comment: Starting to wonder if the rolling and clunk sounds are actually 2 different pieces inside. Gently shaking causes a rolling sound, a slow turn of the whole box causes a clunk. Shaking and turning at the same time seems to cause both rolling and clunking at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

> Keep it on the table, hold two opposite corners and spin it clockwise. If you can't pull or slide it apart then spin it anticlockwise.

Or you can try

> To let it stand on one edge. It could be a gravity orientation puzzle.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! That did it. The rolling was a decoy. The clunk on each 90 degree turn was the real hint.

Comment: Nice! Accept the answer please if you can :)